# How to read key value pair from a option file?

Tags: java

I want  to read key value pair from a option file in my application.I want to pass the value as command line argument like debug.

In debug-

```
-debug "option file path"
```

similarly i want to do the same thing in my key value pair

Content of Option file:

```
com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/isjubula = false
```

so as debug here i want to pass

```
-isjubula " path"
```

so that my application can link to this file and could read its content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Java's main method can help you.. Read some documentation and refer to how one can use main method arguments array.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   String commandType = args[0];
   String command = args[1];

   if(commandType.equals("-isjubula"){
         //TODO: your code here...
   }

}
```

I have not added any null checks here.. please add them..

You can run this type of java progrm after compiling it and running it like
java TestClass "-isjubula" "hello world";

Comment: I donot have main method .It is RCP

Comment: then, you can try this.. this tells you how to pass command line arguments to RCP http://blog.vogella.com/2008/06/21/passing-parameters-to-eclipse-rcp-via-the-command-line/

Comment: Tried but however it is reurning plugin name name only

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem with :

```
public class MyClass{
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        if(args.length == 2 && args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("-isjubula")) {
            System.out.println(args[1]); //get the option
        }
        else {
           System.out.println("Illegal options");
        }
    }
}
```

You can provide option to the above program, while running it in the command line like bellow:

```
java MyClass -isjubula "/home/myconf.conf"
```

or

```
java MyClass -isjubula /home/myconf.conf
```

***Edit:***

No, there is still no facility like this. But one thing you should know, the way of taking `debug` option like mentioned [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_use_the_platform_debug_tracing_facility%3F), is known as [instrumentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_%28computer_programming%29). Generally instrumentation is totally platform dependant. But ideally, you should not use something in your code that will make it solely `eclipse` dependant!

Comment: Sorry .. i think you did not get my question.

Comment: Suppose you are running a program in debug mode  than you have to pass parameter -debug "path" internally it will look for some .options file and then it will take true or false which was already there in option file ..

Comment: Please refer this link if i am not clear to you  http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_use_the_platform_debug_tracing_facility%3F

Comment: This is by eclipse for debug but i want to have custom option instead of debug

Comment: My application is limited to eclipse only .It is RCP .So i Have no main method

Comment: yup tried but it will return only plugin name not the path and debug option

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way. Please see the code below.

```
    //code
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<String> st = Arrays.asList(args);
            if (st.contains("-zipfile")) {
                if (st.indexOf((st.indexOf("-zipFile") + 1)) != -1) {
                    // TODO your code
                }
            }

            if (st.contains("-priority")) {
                if (st.indexOf((st.indexOf("-priority") + 1)) != -1) {
                    // TODO your code
                }
            }
        }
    }
```